# CURL PHP sends blank form

Tags: php, curl

I created a form named question_control.php which has 5 fields, question, op1,op2,op3 and op4. The form takes the parameter and sends it to object.php which in turn writes the data to a file in the form of objects of a class.

```
    <form action="object.php" method="GET">
```

I tried sending the data to question_control.php and found that no data is written to the file. When I tried sending data to object.php I found that new object has been created but all the fields are empty. I tred curl_errno() to see if any error occured but it returns 0. Here's the code

```
<?php

    $curl_connection = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/project/object.php');

    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/25.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $post_data['question'] = 'My';
    $post_data['op1'] = '11';
    $post_data['op2'] = '22';
    $post_data['op3'] = '33';
    $post_data['op4'] = '44';

    foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) 
    {
        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

    print $post_string."\n";

    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

    $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

    print $result;

    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
    echo curl_errno($curl_connection)."\n";

    curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);` add this option and try again

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar `cURL` will automatically switch to POST if POSTFIELDS are specified.

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar Tried. It still sends a blank form.

Comment: @arkascha , i know that, only i want check :) , thanks anyway :)

Comment: @7_R3X $post_string , query string was correct ?!

Comment: It probably makes sense to do a little debugging to find out _where_ exactly the issue is. I suggest you take a closer look at the request that is sent: 1. check the receiving systems access log file to find out about type and size of the request. 2. add logging to the receiving script and dump the `$_POST` superglobal and 3. take a network sniffer like `tcpdump` or `wireshark` and capture the request to take a close look at it.

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar Yes it was. `question=My&op1=11&op2=22&op3=33&op4=44` was the output.

Comment: @arkascha Wireshark!! I'm working entirely on localhost.

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: @arkascha , one time , i have problem with this method , when i spend sometime , i figure that , problem come from post_string, so i decided to write it again

Comment: @arkascha No it doesn't but that's gonna take a long time as I've never used such network monitoring tools before.

Comment: Actually it is not necessary to construct that string yourself, actually it is a risk. Instead you have two options, both more safe: 1. just pass over the associative array you have, `cURL` will take care to encode it correctly or, for a more complex array, use phps `http_build_query()` for the same purpose.

Comment: If you hesitate to use `wireshark`, then take a look at the two other options I suggested first.

Comment: @7_R3X , try it yourself , and monitoring your post with inspect element (F12) chrome browser . CURL is a bot , try making request yourself and see whats going on , and check agian.

Comment: @arkascha even http_build_query() didn't work. I tried a little experiment though. I opened  question_control.php from browser and submitted the form. The URL, when transferred to object.php looks like `127.0.0.1/project/object.php?question=My&op1=11&op2=22&op3=33&op4=44&imagesubmit.x=27&imagesubmit.y=36` but my $post_string after http_build_query() looks like `question=My&op1=11&op2=22&op3=33&op4=44`. What about the submit button? Could it be the source of error?

Comment: You confuse `GET` with `POST` requests. No wonder the receiving script fails to read the transmitted values...

Comment: @arkascha : Sorry I didn't get you. Where did I went wrong exactly?

Comment: The example from the browser uses an http GET request, _not_ an http POST request. Those are two different ways of transferring data. Both transfer the same payload in this case, but the issue is that the receiving side will only look for values being transferred as GET parameters, not as POST parameters. You have to make a GET request with cURL, not a POST request.

Comment: I posted a short answer below to show the basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion in the comments to the question you actually have to make a `GET` request, not a `POST` request.

So have a try with this approach:

```
<?php
$query_parameters = http_build_query([
    'question' => 'My',
    'op1' => '11',
    'op2' => '22',
    'op3' => '33',
    'op4' => '44'
]);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1/project/object.php?' . $query_parameters);
// ... more curl_setopt(...) calls ...
```

So you attach the query parameters to the URL by means of the query separator `?` and you do *not* specify any POST fields for the request. GET is the default for cURL, so nothing more you have to take care of.

Comment: I tried it this way but it still sent a blank form. So I tried adding the button field as I doubted earlier. It worked!!!! I think it's because the script on the server side is written to act in such a way that it only writes data to the file if the button field is set. Thanks anyway. You've been a great help. :)

Comment: OK, I would translate your experience like that: in addition to switching the transfer method from POST to GET you additionally had to add some missing parameter the receiving script expects. Sounds like a classical example why documentation of an API is such an important thing.... Glad you sorted things out!

Answer (score 0):

Use `http_build_query` function to generate urlencoded string for passing into request:

```
...
$post_data['question'] = 'My';
$post_data['op1'] = '11';
$post_data['op2'] = '22';
$post_data['op3'] = '33';
$post_data['op4'] = '44';
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data, '', '&'));
...
```

Comment: I tried it your way but it still doesn't work. It sends a blank form as before

Answer (score 0):

I have perhaps missed the point of the initial setting of the `$post_data` array with static values but as you are submitting the form via GET why not simply use the values entered in the form?

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init( 'http://127.0.0.1/project/object.php' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/25.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    /* automatically generate the required post data using the $_GET array data sent by the form */
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $_GET ) );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    $info=curl_getinfo( $ch );
    $errors=curl_errno( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    if( !empty( $result ) ) echo $result;
    if( !empty( $info ) ) print_r( $info );
    if( !empty( $errors ) ) print_r( $errors );
?>
```